# ChangeFeed - Last Successful Operation Processed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The code snippet below iterates over the change feed.  If we need to track the last successful processed record is that calculated by the continuation plus index (continuation + i) in the loop and/or the ETag of the document.  IF there is a failure, how do I query the changefeed from that exact place?  It isn't clear because when I start at 0 and request 1000, the continuation token in my test was 1120.

```
IDocumentQuery < Document > query = client.CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery(
 collectionUri,
 new ChangeFeedOptions {
  PartitionKeyRangeId = pkRange.Id,
   StartFromBeginning = true,
   RequestContinuation = continuation,
   MaxItemCount = 1000
 });

while (query.HasMoreResults) {

 Dictionary < string, BlastTimeRange > br = new Dictionary < string, BlastTimeRange > ();
 var readChangesResponse = query.ExecuteNextAsync < Document > ().Result;
 int i =0;
 foreach(Document changedDocument in readChangesResponse.AsEnumerable().ToList()) {
   // processing each one
   // the continuation and i represent the place or is it better to store off the ETag?  
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this today is track the continuation token (same as the `ETag` in REST API), and the list of `_rid` values for the documents that you've read within the batch. When you read the next batch, you must exclude the `_rid` values that you have processed before.

The easiest way to do this without writing custom code is to use the DocumentDB team's ChangeFeedProcessor library (in preview). In order to get access. please email askdocdb@microsoft.com.